# Input fields are overlapping. Cannot display them inline

Tags: html, css

I have a page where there are several input fields that overlap, and cannot seem to display them inline to their labels.

Any ideas on how to put the input filed next to the label?  Have tried everything and cant seem to do it.

Example here.

http://www.healthinteractive.co.uk/assess/node/3/done?sid=44

Thanks, from a noob.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way I'd normally align labels and input fields would be to float both the label and the input to the left, and then set clear left on the label.

Something like:

```
label, input { float:left; }
label { clear:left; }
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/MVu9y/

Comment: @JonnyHI: Welcome to StackOverflow :)  If Jamie's answer fixed your problem (which I assume it did) you should click the tick on the left to accept it.